# cookie encryption

Tags: java

how to encrypt cookies as it accepts only US-ASCII characters? when i use  below code, it generates characters out of US_ASCII. how to limit encrypted characters not to go out of US_ASCII?

```
        key = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm).generateKey();
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
        messageSource.getMessage("encryption.algorithm",null,localeUtil.getLocale());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());
```

Answer (score 7):

Firstly: don't use `String.getBytes` without specifying an encoding, preferably something which can handle all of Unicode, such as UTF-8.

Secondly: the code you've given doesn't generate *characters* at all - it generates *bytes*. You *mustn't* treat those bytes as if they're encoded text - they're not. Instead, you should convert them to base64, e.g. with [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) or [this public domain code](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/).

Then when you need to decrypt, you simply reverse all the steps - convert back from base64 to binary, decrypt, and then create a string with `new String(decryptedBytes, "UTF-8")` (or whatever encoding you decided to use).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String CHARSET = "ISO-8859-1";

String text = "Ángel";
String encodedText = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(text.getBytes(CHARSET)));
String decodedText = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(encodedText.getBytes(CHARSET)))
```

In addition to Jon's answer, you can view the available encodings here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html